# Which is the correct USA specific tld

Tags: seo

Which is the correct USA tld to use?

I ask this because i thought it was .us but it can be purchased on any domain provider like godaddy and name.com which is weird.

I thought only USA citizens would be able to buy USA specific tld and get the SEO BOOST

Comment: SEO boost?... its a domain, don't expect a boost for having a domain.

Answer (score 3):

> Which is the correct USA specific tld

`.us` (Reference: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.us))

> I ask this because i thought it was .us but it can be purchased on any domain provider like godaddy and name.com which is weird.

Just because a product is available in an international marketplace doesn't make it exempt from the terms and conditions associated with that product.

Many ccTLDs have specific registration requirements that must be met.

> I thought only USA citizens would be able to buy USA specific tld

From the Wikipedia article (linked above):

> Registrants of .us domains must be United States citizens, residents, or organizations, or a foreign entity with **a presence in the United States**.

Both [GoDaddy](https://uk.godaddy.com/tlds/us.aspx) and [name.com](https://www.name.com/domains/us) state similar on their websites, although admittedly this information is not made immediately obvious.

As I understand it, you are required to provide a full US postal address upon registration. I have [also read that](https://www.101domain.com/us.htm) "Nameservers must be physically located in the U.S.".

> To ensure that these requirements are met, Neustar frequently conducts "spot checks" on registrant information.
>
> To prevent anonymous registrations that do not meet these requirements, in 2005 the National Telecommunications and Information Administration ruled that registrants of .us domains may not secure private domain name registration via anonymizing proxies, and that their contact information must be made public. Registrants are required to provide complete contact information without omissions.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.us)